# Upload and Email in the Same Code (VBA)

Tags: vba

I'm currently using Microsoft Access to send weekly emails. The goal of the code is to send out emails, with a report attached, to my managers and then upload them into SharePoint. The problems is that it can send out the email and upload reports separately, but when I put them into the same code and run it, it does the first task, but not the other.

```
 DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "TestingReport", acFormatPDF, "testing@gmail.com", , , "Testing", "Test", False

 Dim MyPath As String
 Dim MyFiLeName As String
 MyFilter = ""
 MyPath = "https://www.testing.com/"
 MyFiLeName = "Weekly Report_" & Int(Format(Date, "m")) & "_" & Int(Format(Date, "d")) & "_" & Year(Date) & ".pdf"

 DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "TestingReport",acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFiLeName, False
```

Could it be the time and speed issue? I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: side note : You can use `format(date,"m_d_y")` or `month` `day` `year` functions

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks!